# nativescript angular template form *ngif not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have a template driven form and I want to add some validation to a text field. I'm using nativescript playground with angular and typescript.
The first label with *ngIf is working fine, for the 2nd one nothing happens and I also do not get an error massage. I already tried:

*ngIf="endTime.errors?.minlength
*ngIf="endTime?.errors?.minlength

nothing works. Does any one have a solution for me? Do I need to nest the labels?

````
     ```   <TextField id="endTime" #endTime="ngModel"
            hint=" Enter end time 00:00" [(ngModel)]="t1" secure="false"
            keyboardType="datetime" returnKeyType="done"
            autocorrect="false" maxLength="5" minLength="5"
            class="input input-border" required>
        </TextField>

        <Label class="text-danger" textWrap="true"
            *ngIf="endTime.touched && !endTime.valid"
            text="End time is required!"> </Label>

        <Label class="text-danger" textWrap="true"
            *ngIf="endTime.errors?.minLength"
            text="End time must be format hh:mm"> </Label> ```
````

Comment: Can you post the link to the playground app?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=groceries-ng&id=sC4ZiK&v=475

Comment: you can find it in zeit component.html